# align gridview columns to left and right dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview. I am dynmically binding the gridview in code behind using a datatable. There are only two columns in my gridview, one is a text column and another one is a numeric column. I want to align the left column, the text column to left, and the numeric column to right. Below is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
dt.Columns.Add("Fee Breakdown", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add(" ", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("First Page", String.Format("{0:0.00}", 14));
dt.Rows.Add("Additional Page(s)", String.Format("{0:0.00}", 3));
        
        
protected void grdCalculate_rowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                
    }
}
```

The numbers 14 and 3 in dt.rows.add is a dynamically calculated value and the number of digits can increase and decrease. The above code in rowsdatabound is not aligning the columns to left and right, I am trying to align the columns so that all decimals can be right-aligned properly and its easier to add the numbers. Below is the picture of gridview. As you can see the decimals are not aliged properly in $14.00 and $3.00. How can I align the first row to left and the right row to right. Below is my aspx page code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCalculate" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDataBound="grdCalculate_RowDataBound" ></asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this format:

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[3].Text));
        }
    }
```

And then JUST shove in the value at bind time.

eg:

```
dt.Rows.Add("First Page", 14);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is bit different approach, but you can try using the below as you have two columns to bind:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCalculate" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDataBound="grdCalculate_RowDataBound">
 <columns>
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Name">
       <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Property_Name_1")%></ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Price">
       <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Property_Name_2")%></ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Just used this **ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign** property in the GridView's header.